# django, getting objects from database to the template in viewable form

Tags: python, django, pandas

I'm new to Django, and the question is how to how to pass variables from the database to the template in a form where they are visible. The information in the database and model was created by using pandas to take the CSV file and to create the model. After a little searching around I was able to add a primary key to data base and when using /admin I am able to see that the db is populated with information from the CVS file. Now the problem seems to be that an object is being passed to the template rather than a string that would be visible.

In the views I have

```
def newsinspector(request):
    df=Df.objects.all()
    return render(request,'boards/the_file.html',{'df':df})
```

In the template I have

```
<h1>Title: {{ df.Name }}</h1>
<p><strong>My info:</strong> {% for d in df.all %}{{d.name}}{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}{% endfor %}</p>
```

The model generated by the inspectdb looks like

```
    class Df(models.Model):
        index = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=True, null=False)
        user_rank = models.IntegerField(db_column='User_Rank', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        name = models.TextField(db_column='Newspaper_Name', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        # some other similar fields mostly TextFields


        class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = 'df'
```

The issue is that I seem to be passing an object rather than a string that could be used in the HTML. 
For example I get something
like

Title:

My Info: Df object (0), Df object (1), Df object (2), Df object (3),

When I would I would like to have something like

Title: name

My Info: item1, item2, item3, etc....

When I replace the dictionary in the view ('df':df} with a string the variable passes and prints in template html file like I expect it should.

So somewhere I am missing how to turn the db object into a string. Help?

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you want here. `df` doesn't have a name attribute, because it is a queryset - ie a list of *all* the objects in the database.

But inside your loop, each `d` *does* have a name attribute. So you can do:

```
 {% for d in df %}{{ d.name }}{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

(Or you could just as well do `d.index`, or whatever you want.)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear in the post. If in the double curly brackets I put  d.name I don't get any output on the html page. I edited the post to be more clear.

Comment: Oops, took a closer look and found that I have name attribute capitalized when it shouldn't have been. I think it seems to be working now due to Daniels helpful comment.